# To set adapter for a Expandable listview

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, expandablelistadapter, expandable

I'm trying to set an adapter for a expandable list view as follows:

```
public class CompanyProfileAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

Context context;
ArrayList<SearchListView> searchresultList;
ArrayList<IndustryListView> industryListViews;

public CompanyProfileAdapter(Context context,
        ArrayList<IndustryListView> industryListViews,
        ArrayList<SearchListView> searchresultList) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    this.searchresultList = searchresultList;
    this.industryListViews = industryListViews;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return industryListViews.get(this.searchresultList.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}
```

here I'm getting this following error: "The method get(int) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (SearchListView)"

in the last line of the above code. Can anyone please help me solving this issue.

Comment: In which line are you getting error?Can you post your stacktrace

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm getting error in the return statement of the getChild() method.

Comment: the method  ->  industryListViews.get(int index)  accept int, not SearchListView.

Answer (score 0):

It is true will be nice to have more info. Normally, when you report an error try to copy/paste the stacktrace of this error from your logcat.

Anyway, i have the feeling your problem is comming because you are not updating properly the methods "getChildrenCount" and "getGroupCount".

In this methods you should update with the lenght of you lists:

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) 
{
    return searchresultList.size();
}


@Override
public int getGroupCount() 
{
    return industryListViews.size();
}
```

I am taking on industryListViews as the group/header list, and searchresultList as the child list.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different array list .. i think the problem is .

```
    ArrayList<SearchListView> searchresultList;
    ArrayList<IndustryListView> industryListViews;
```

look your code where you are getting error. 
you wrote

```
return industryListViews.get(this.searchresultList.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
```

Actually this kind of code is not applicable for an ArrayList.
You need to use **HashMap** like this `private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> industryListViews;`

For more information about this, you can follow this tutorial
[ExpandableListView](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)